# How to stop setOnItemSelectedListener from running in onCreate

Tags: android, listener, oncreate

I set values in my setOnItemSelectedListener depending on what is selected in my spinner.

How can I stop this method being called onCreate?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Set `setOnItemSelectedListener` for your spinner not onItemClickListener

Take a boolean field like this

```
boolean onload=false;
```

And the in your `oncreate`

set

```
 onload=true;
```

And in your onItemSelectedListener, do like this

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
     if(!onload)
     {              
     }
onload=false;
    }
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    }
});
```

Comment: see edited question, do you understand where i'm coming from? In onItemSelected I set my wattage variable depending on what is selected in the spinner, but I want to be able to load a custom wattage value, so basically I need to skip this setOnItemSelectedListener method

Comment: @Chris What I need to understand? And where do you coming from? I have provided answer based on your question. do you think this information will be enough to provide answer?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16460101/load-data-setonitemselectedlistener for more detail, i'll be deleting this question shortly

Comment: @Chris Delete this if you can..I'll look at that question

Comment: thanks, I just cant get my head around it